Why is the return type of `.map(…)` over an iterator so complicated?
I have this code:
let mut myFile = readFile();
let reader = BufReader::new(myFile);
let tasks = reader.lines()
        .map(|line| line.expect("Couldn't read line"));

When I hover over 'tasks', I see this:

let tasks: Map<Lines<BufReader<File>>, fn(Result<String>) -> String>


Looking at the code:
reader.lines() gives an iterator over lines in the file.
map() takes a function/closure(which performs some action on each line and return another value).
So I expect return value of map() to be another data structure which represents a list of values.
Why it is instead a Map?

Iterators in rust are lazy. When you call some_iterator.lines(...).map(...), no actual iteration is done. Instead, a chain or a "russian doll" structure is set up, where each iterator wraps the one before it.
They will all start executing when you attempt to actually use the result of the iterator. By reading it in a loop, for example. If you want to perform the calculation now and use the result later, add a .collect() at the end of the iterator chain (you might have to specify the collection you want to get back, .collect::<Vec<_>>() or so).

Ok, got it. Its like java stream which also is evaluated lazily and return type for stream methods is another stream.

@Mandroid Yep, pretty much.

@Mandroid True, except in Java streams (and the functions they call) return an interface, meaning they're (heap allocated and) dynamically dispatched, while in Rust there is neither allocation nor dynamic dispatch, which means iterator chains compile to extremely efficient machine code, often equivalent and sometimes better than hand-written loops.

@ChayimFriedman, if their is no memory allocation(stack or heap), then how are things stored? They need to be put in memory somehow, isn't? Can you please elaborate.

@Mandroid: Their memory is on the stack (so no heap allocation), and they are statically typed (so no dynamic dispatch).

@Mandroid In addition to what eggyal said, often they do not need to carry state (e.g. map() with captureless callback), so they have no allocation at all.

Also note that you almost certainly never need to name the type of an iterator because you can either collect it immediately or, if returning from a function, can return impl Iterator<Item=Whatever> (which hides everything about the iterator except its Item from callers without changing the strongly typed, Russian doll nature of it).
